# Custom frame in PyQt5 is not expanding properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am attempting to create a UI through PyQt5. I wanted to create a custom clickable frame because the push button did not have the formatting capabilities I was looking for. However, when I run the program the custom buttons are not expanding to fill the available horizontal space.

```
class ApplicationPage(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class ClickableFrame(QFrame):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, title, description, icon_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Create a layout for the ClickableFrame
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        # Create QLabel for the icon
        icon_label = QLabel()
        icon = QIcon(icon_path).pixmap(QSize(70, 70))  # Use QIcon for SVG
        icon_label.setPixmap(icon)
        icon_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        layout.addWidget(icon_label)

        # Create a vertical layout for the title and description
        text_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        text_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        text_layout.setSpacing(0)

        # Create QLabel for the header (title)
        title_label = QLabel(title)
        title_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 20, weight=QtGui.QFont.Bold))
        title_label.setStyleSheet("color: white") 
        title_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        text_layout.addWidget(title_label)

        # Create QLabel for the description
        description_label = QLabel(description)
        description_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        description_label.setStyleSheet("color: white")
        description_label.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        text_layout.addWidget(description_label)

        # Add the text layout to the main layout
        layout.addLayout(text_layout)
        layout.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
       
        # Set the frame to expand horizontally and align to the left
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.layout().setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        print(f"{self.objectName()} size policy set to:", self.sizePolicy().horizontalPolicy(), self.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy())

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() 
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setup_tools_page()
        QApplication.setStyle(QApplication.style())

        # Create the clickable frames and connect them to page switching methods
        self.create_clickable_frame(
            self.ui.CorpBtnFrame, self.ui.CORPButton, "Corporate Account Linker",
            " A tool for finding accounts that should be connected to a Corporate Account.",
            "c:\\PythonLocal\\PyGUI\\feather\\link.svg", self.show_corp_page
        )
        #This is replicated 5 times for each tool button
    def setup_tools_page(self):
        # Retrieve the layout for the Tools page
        tools_layout = self.ui.verticalLayout_58

        button_frames = ['CorpBtnFrame', 'DLABtnFrame', 'DLCBtnFrame', 'MatchBtnFrame', 'TSEBtnFrame']
        button_widgets = ['CORPButton', 'DLAButton', 'DLCButton', 'MatchButton', 'TSEButton']

    # Make sure a layout is set for frame_widget before adding ClickableFrame
        for frame_name in ['CorpBtnFrame', 'DLABtnFrame', 'DLCBtnFrame', 'MatchBtnFrame', 'TSEBtnFrame']:
            frame_widget = getattr(self.ui, frame_name)
            if not frame_widget.layout():
                # If there is no layout, set one
                frame_widget.setLayout(QHBoxLayout())
            frame_widget.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)  # Ensure the frame can expand

        tools_layout.addStretch(1)

        # Get the layout for ToolsPage
        tools_layout = self.ui.verticalLayout_58

        self.adjustSize()

    def create_clickable_frame(self, frame, button, title, description, icon_path, page_switch_method):
        # Ensure that 'button' has a layout and set its size policy to expand
        layout = button.layout()
        if layout is None:
            layout = QVBoxLayout()
            button.setLayout(layout)
        button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        # Create the ClickableFrame, set its size policy, and add it to the layout
        clickable_frame = ClickableFrame(title, description, icon_path)
        clickable_frame.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        layout.addWidget(clickable_frame)

        # Connect the clicked signal to the page switch method
        clickable_frame.clicked.connect(page_switch_method)
```

Picture of Object Inspector in Designer.

[image: Object Inspector]

Picture of the UI when the file is ran.

[image: UI currently]

I want the clickable frames to take up the entire horizontal space within Toolsframe. I have reviewed every parent object in designer an ensured that every parent object to the custom frame was set to expanding. I have attempt to add stretch to the clickable frame. I also redrew and forced the page to update. Below is a relevant snippet from the output of Designer.

```
                  <widget class="QFrame" name="ToolsFrame">
                   <property name="sizePolicy">
                    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
                     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                    </sizepolicy>
                   </property>
                   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_10">
                    <property name="spacing">
                     <number>18</number>
                    </property>
                    <property name="leftMargin">
                     <number>25</number>
                    </property>
                    <property name="topMargin">
                     <number>25</number>
                    </property>
                    <property name="rightMargin">
                     <number>25</number>
                    </property>
                    <property name="bottomMargin">
                     <number>25</number>
                    </property>
                    <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
                     <widget class="QWidget" name="DLAButton" native="true">
                      <property name="sizePolicy">
                       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Maximum">
                        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                       </sizepolicy>
                      </property>
                      <property name="maximumSize">
                       <size>
                        <width>16777215</width>
                        <height>16777215</height>
                       </size>
                      </property>
                      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_20">
                       <property name="spacing">
                        <number>0</number>
                       </property>
                       <property name="leftMargin">
                        <number>0</number>
                       </property>
                       <property name="topMargin">
                        <number>0</number>
                       </property>
                       <property name="rightMargin">
                        <number>0</number>
                       </property>
                       <property name="bottomMargin">
                        <number>0</number>
                       </property>
                       <item>
                        <widget class="QFrame" name="DLABtnFrame">
                         <property name="sizePolicy">
                          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Maximum">
                           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
                           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
                          </sizepolicy>
                         </property>
                         <property name="frameShape">
                          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
                         </property>
                         <property name="frameShadow">
                          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
                         </property>
                        </widget>
                       </item>
                      </layout>
                     </widget>
                    </item>
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand you, because your code is a bit convoluted and you only provided a snippet of the UI, making it impossible to test it. In any case: 1. `DLAButton` seems to be left aligned (which will make its contents completely moved to the left respecting their size hint, instead of occupying all the available space); 2. you're doing the same in the custom widget, by setting the alignment of the layout; 3. do not use `if not frame_widget.layout()`, but `if frame_widget.layout() is None`.